# Photo Competition 2021-03-29: Transportation

Tags: photo-competition

#### Theme

The theme of this contest is simply transportation. Trains, cars, ships, planes, bicycles, etc.

This theme was suggested by [Matt](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/80733/matt).

#### Voting Rules

- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on March 29, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.**
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

- Suggest a theme for the next contest. Leave a single comment below in the format,

  > Theme: <*one sentence description*>
- Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next time.

Good luck!

Comment: Theme: Up there. Subjects in the photo should be unsupported by the ground. Examples include airplanes, balloons, bubbles, water splashes, astrophotography, clouds, birds/insects/animals in flight, etc.

Comment: Theme: Repetition: The subject of the photo should have repeated elements.  Examples: A jar of marbles, a production line, a crowd.

Comment: Theme: Transition. Subjects can include seasons, openings, people... Anything that's in the midst of some sort of transition from one state to another. Examples might include spring flowers in the snow; makeup being applied; car undergoing restoration...

Comment: Theme: IRL Sci-Fi. Subject should be something IRL that looks like it came out of a Sci-Fi movie. :)

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 Great theme suggestion. It's now the [current competition theme](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124247/11924)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## No Parking

Our neighbours woke us up in the middle of the night with "I think you ought to come & see this…"

The Merc that the BMW came to rest against is mine. The driver had managed to lose control so spectacularly that he wrote off 6 cars on a road only 80 metres long, some much worse than you can see here, he'd managed to surf along a few.
Mine was miraculously untouched.

[image]

<sup>Nikon D5500 50mm 1.4 2xGodox V860II - one on-camera, the other held by the neighbour.

Sept 2017, North London.</sup>

Comment: Oof. I'm genuinely surprised that your car came out of this unscathed. I like this picture because it's a slice of life that most of us (thankfully) don't see every day.

Comment: Indeed. I do have to hope it's a once in a lifetime occurrence;) It wasn't possible to tell it wasn't actually bent around my car until it was carefully pulled away. This is from the other side - https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8US7.jpg

Comment: Clearly a master at work.  Hit all those other cars, just to make a your-car shaped space in his front end...

Comment: I see your sleep is not easily disturbed.. :)

Comment: Because of the parking zoning structure around here, I don't live in ear-shot of where this happened. BTW, no drunk drivers were actually hurt in the making of this photograph… though they were arrested at the scene & probably will not be driving again for a while. There are 3 attending police cars hidden by the Beemer centre-stage in this drama.

Answer (score 30):

## Tired man after work

Ho Chi Minh city - 29-Jan-2019

[image: Man after work]

Answer (score 27):

Location: Kerala, India
Subject: Aircraft
Date: 2020-07-22
Camera: Nikon D5600
f/9, 1/320, 195 mm

*Waves of cloud!*
[image]

Answer (score 25):

Location: San Francisco

Subject: Bustling Bay Bridge

Date: 6/27/2020

[image: Busy]

Answer (score 25):

## One-horse open sleigh

Germany, 2021-02-14

[image: One-horse open sleigh]

Taken with a Sony DSC-R1 compact camera, used RawTherapee for producing a JPEG from raw.

Comment: Guess the shadow looks fine, but the lack of horse trails somehow makes this look totally photoshopped.

Comment: Well, the sun was low.  If I had photoshopped this, I'd certainly have tried to do better than that octopus shaped shadow that overlaps so badly with the shadow from the out-of-sight fence that you cannot really decide whether all four hooves are off the ground.  Also a gallopping Shetland pony makes way less of an impression on a hard snow surface than sliding tracks.  Try dragging a sleigh across ground where hoof prints are prominent.  No obvious boot tracks either.  This is from the raw with only global adjustments. Camera JPEG is more washed-out and with less suitable white balance.

Comment: I didn't actually mean it IS photoshopped, I just found it interesting that it looks so much like it could be. Guess the light is so perfect that the pony looks like a stock photo, and the fact that is has all four feet off the ground also contributes.

Comment: Well, I am not too sure about the dynamics of hooves on hard snow.  You'll see some scant billows of snow near the left hooves where apparently the snow was thrown up by the hooves but it's pretty hopeless to see where the hooves may actually have touched.  I guess this is one example of a photograph where you'd need to invest a bit of photoshopping in order to stop it from looking photoshopped.

Answer (score 24):

[image: Tram in the Rain]

Subject: Tram in the Rain

Location: Milan

Date: 10/13/2016

Answer (score 20):

Riding the Tokyo Metro, Tokyo, April 2007

[image: Tokyo Metro]

Answer (score 18):

Location: German/Czech border near Zschirnstein

Subject: Old Multi-car in a Backyard

Date: Nov 2011

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Location: Kettering
Subject: Rush hour
Date: 15/01/2020
[image]

Comment: I'm a sucker for these sorts of shots, but it doesn't appear in focus which is a shame.

Comment: It has motion blur due to camera shake

Comment: @Nayuki The heavy traffic created quite a lot of very noticeable vibration through the narrow bridge I was standing on. Especially the big trucks! The shutter was on a 2 second delay, so there shouldn't have been any button press related shake!

Answer (score 17):

[image: Freight cars at Hannover Nordhafen]

Subject: Freight cars at an inland port on Mittelland Canal
Location: Nordhafen, Hannover, Germany
Date: 2012-04-23

This was a spontaneous shot on an iPhone 4s on a bike commute along the canal quite some time ago. Only afterwards I noticed the strong symmetry of the different freight cars which I enhanced by cropping the original image. I recently reedited the image to get a print of it.

Comment: I really like the symmetry of this shot. I keep coming back to it. +250. =)

Answer (score 16):

## The duck hawker

Ho Chi Minh city - 29-Dec-2019

[image: Duck hawker]

Comment: Folks, please respect the contest rules and do not downvote. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120935/discussion-on-answer-by-phuclv-photo-competition-2021-03-29-transportation).

Answer (score 15):

Location: Devon, UK

Subject: Abandoned Industrial Rail Line

Date: 2016/11/03

[image: Picture looking down an abandoned railway and railway bridge on a grey autumn day with some yellow leaves on the ground and the trees on the edges of the image are green and yellow and orange.]

Answer (score 14):

Abandoned bus at the Pripyat police station, 07-Aug-2019 (my first time properly using a camera, I bought it specifically for the trip)

[image: Abandoned bus at the Pripyat police station, 07-Aug-2019]

Comment: [PAZ-672](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:PAZ-672), it seems.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Location: Georgia Strait

Subject: Freighter

Date: January 2021

Answer (score 11):

### Mid-intersection waiting

Location: Silom Road in Bangkok

Date taken: 15 March 2021

[image]

8 seconds, f/7.1, ISO 100, and zoomed in 73mm (not sure if that's correct or some equivalency measure, but that's what it says in the RAW file) using a Sony RX10M3.

Answer (score 11):

Location: Los Angeles

Subject: Metro railcar storage

Date: January 24, 2020

[image]

Answer (score 10):

## Under the Hood

Location: Knoxville, TN

Subject: The under side of the open hood of a Chevy Hotrod

Date: 2019-04-19

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Location: Somewhere above the pacific

Subject: Commercial airplane row

Date: June 27, 2019

Shot with Olympus OM-1 on Ilford HP5 Plus

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Subject: Kings Highway Interlocking,
Location: BMT Brighton Line, New York City
Date: September 26, 2020

[image]

Taken on a Pixel 4 while waiting for the train (seen in the photo on the local track) to arrive.

Answer (score 9):

Subject: Manhattan Bridge,
Location: Brooklyn Bridge Park, Brooklyn, NY
Date: October 9, 2020

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Vision of a cloud through a moving tree, transporting dreams in a train water in clouds, electricity in cables. The tree and the movement act like filters to see the clouds.

On the train between *Firenze i Siena, Italia*, 27th of april 2012.

[image: transportation of a dream]

Comment: Folks, please respect the rules and do not downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Location: Auckland Airport

Subject: Abandoned airport scene

Date: 2019-05-19

[image: Auckland Airport scene]

[Original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/48812180598/)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Location: Vienna

Date: 2014-03-25

Subject: Horse drawn carriage

Answer (score 8):

Location: Greifswald, Germany

Subject: Regional express train

Date: 14.08.2012

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Cotton candy man

Ho Chi Minh city - 11-Dec-2020

[image: Cotton candy]

Answer (score 7):

Tokyo, Commuters on their way home, October 2019

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Location: Sydney, Australia

Subject: VW Beetle under a No Stopping Sign

Date: 2021-03-01 @ 5:31PM

[image: A VW Beetle in sepia, parked on an incline under a 'No Stopping' sign.]

Comment: `Police officer:` The sign says "No Stopping". `Driver:` You tell that to the car!

Answer (score 6):

Location: Istanbul, Straits of Bosphorus

Subject: Safe And Sound

Date: February 3rd, 2021

[image: Safe And Sound]

Shot on Ilford Hp5+ 400 film, pushed twice to 1600 ISO on Canon AE-1 Program. Self developed with Ilfosol developer

Answer (score 5):

Inland Sea of Japan, Ferry between Shodoshima and Naoshima, October 2019

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tram from Wimbledon crosses over River Wandle on edge of Morden Hall Park. London, England. 9th March 2021[image]

Answer (score 5):

### An Italian masterpiece with a German heart.

This image was taken at Toronto Motorsports Park Cayuga, in Cayuga, Ontario Canada on September 27th, 2017.

[image: Pagani Huayra BC]

Comment: be still my heart. The interior of that car is an absolute work of art.

Comment: @scottbb what's the car model?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. The [Pagani Huayra](https://external-preview.redd.it/_JopNI21S1fWqWkm3oqO3H9V2sSSTVg8wsTfxIdf3q4.jpg?auto=webp&s=6b144730a1a2e2eda3b30e2f7f055b8cbc65f18b). It has manumatic paddle shifters, if you really want them. But the machined exposed shifter mechanism is just... _gorgeous_.

Comment: @scottbb very nice!

Answer (score 4):

The daily commute. Mumbai, India. January 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Location: Amsterdam
Subject: Pirate ship
Date: May 2017
Camera: Redmi 4 Prime, I lost the original photo so idk it's metadata.

[image: Pirate ship on Amsterdam]

Answer (score 4):

Location: Istanbul

Subject: Streetcar

Date: 09/2012

[image: Car train in Istanbul]

Answer (score 4):

Preston, UK

Train Tracks

December 2020

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Location: San Francisco

Subject: Bridging the Gap

Date: 6/29/2020

[image: Bridging the Gap]

Answer (score 3):

Location: Bodø, Norway

Subject: Hurtigruten arriving at Bodø for the Constitution Day celebration

Date: 2019-05-17

[image: Hurtigruten arriving at Bodø]

Barely visible in the near background are the cannoneers who just fired a salute from Nyholmen Skandse. The far background is Lille Hjartøya.

[Original](https://www.flickr.com/photos/l0b0/48812179278/)

Answer (score 3):

### Police escort for quarantine arrivals

Location: Suvarnabhumi airport in Bangkok

Date taken: 12 March 2021

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Three Friends

Location: Lisbon
Subject: Jaguar E-type, Morris Mini, Jaguar Mark VII
Date: July 2020

[image: Three friends]

Answer (score 3):

Location: Nottingham Canal
Subject: Canal Boats
Date: 15th March 2021

[image: Location: Nottingham Canal Subject: Canal Boats Date: 15th March 2021]

Answer (score 3):

### Robot's Revenge

[image]

Paris metro, automatic driverless line. October 2009.

Answer (score 3):

This image was made on the bow of a cruise ship at 5:30am as it was docking at San Francisco.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Location: Toronto

Subject: Eager to Leave vs Eager to Get Home

Date: 2020-10-18

[image]

Comment: Folks, please respect the rules and do not downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @scottbb I do not think anyone downvoted?

Comment: Unfortunately, one person did. =(

Answer (score 2):

### Nightly garbage collection

Location: Silom Road in Bangkok

Date taken: 15 March 2021

[image]

5 second exposure, f/4, ISO 100, and zoomed in 214mm using a Sony RX10M3.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Rainy Day at the Airport.

Airbus A380, the world's largest passenger airliner. Munich Airport (MUC), April 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Location: Preston
Subject: Train line
Date: 26th December 2020

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Vasa

**Vasa Museum, Stockholm (Sweden)**
July 2005

For more info: [Vasa (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasa_(ship))

[image: Vasa]

Answer (score 2):

Auschwitz, Poland

Train that transported Jews to their unknowing death at Auschwitz concentration camp

December 2019

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

Abandoned car in Oulanka National Park, Finland
*12|05|2020*

[image]

Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mk II
*f3.6 | 1/50s | ISO 100 | 15mm*

Answer (score 2):

### Slithering

Erwin Wurm's *Misconceivable* next to the Middelheim castle in Antwerp, Belgium.
*12|07|2020*

[image]

Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mk II
*f/8 | 1/80s | ISO 200 | 45mm*

Answer (score 1):

Location: Moss Landing

Subject: Bonsai Boats

Date: 10/4/2020

[image: Bonsai Boats]

Comment: Folks, please respect the rules and do not downvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Location: Utrecht, Netherlands
Subject: Man navigates a canal in style.
Date: 23/7/2019

The Dutch really know how to take it easy on a summer day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Location: Dayton, KY

Subject: Empty tracks

Date: Feb 2021

Answer (score 0):

### Traffic jam in Jumeirah

**Jumeirah, Dubai, UAE**
September 2005

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Cross on a Truck

[image: Truck on a highway bearing a cross in the back.]

---

March 11th
Los Angeles, CA, USA
Sony Alpha 7S III + Sony FE 85mm F1.4
ISO 800 | 85 mm | ƒ/2.8 | 1/2500 s

Answer (score 0):

### Classic Cars exhibition

**London, UK**
10 July 2010

[image: Classic Car]